# When using <AsyncTypeahead/> I can't use onSearch and onInputChange at the same time

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

So as I said in the title, I can't use onSearch and onInputChange at the same time. If I try to, onSearch gets ignored. Can you tell me why or is there an alternative to onInputChange? Im using AsyncTypeahead in a Form, so I need the values when I click a button.

```
const [from, setFrom] = useState('');
const onSearchStart = (query) => {
  setTypeAhead({
    ...typeAhead,
    startIsLoading: true
   })
   setFrom(query)
   getStations(query).then(r => {
   setTypeAhead({
     ...typeAhead,
     startIsLoading: false,
     startOptions: r || []
   })
 })
}

return(
  <AsyncTypeahead
    id={"from"}
    isLoading={typeAhead.startIsLoading}
    options={typeAhead.startOptions}
    onInputChange={setFrom}
    onSearch={onSearchStart}
  />  
)
```

This isn't the whole code, but it shows everything that is causing the error

Comment: The problem is that your `onInputChange` calls `setFrom`, which updates state and causes the component to re-render. The re-render short-circuits the `onSearch` function, which is debounced. Depending on why you need `onInputChange`, you could try moving `setFrom` into the `onSearch` function instead.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I want to be able to type a search term and if is not found then use the value in the input field, I'm using a similar setup as the question above but I'm struggling getting it to work the way I need it

Comment: After reading over and over the code above and @ericgio comment, I got it working, there is no need to use `onInputChange` to keep track of what has been typed, instead use the search term to do so, so use the state setter inside the `onSearch` method

Comment: @RicardoSanchez how did you get it working? onSearch is fired only if the string exceeded min length which is 2 by default. That means that first 2 characters typed in the input field won't trigger setState. My workaround is to use `useRef()` but i'm curious if anybody found another solution

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use `useRef` to not trigger the re-render. Here is the code:

```
const fromRef = useRef('');
const onSearchStart = (query) => {
  ...
}

return(
  <AsyncTypeahead
    ...
    onInputChange={(text) => {
      fromRef.current = text;
    }}
    onSearch={onSearchStart}
  />  
)
```

Comment: but add onInputChange then onSearch can't be working as well, it displays Type to seach... and no call to server